# warning on std::vector constructor

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to figure out what this piece of code does:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool> > visited(rows, std::vector<bool>(cols, 0));
```

'rows' and 'cols' are both integers.

It calls the constructor, but I'm not sure how.
It's sample code I got from some project...

It's also giving me the following warning:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(2140): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(2126) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>::_BConstruct<_Iter>(_Iter,_Iter,std::_Int_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<bool>,
1>              _Iter=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\ai challenge\code\project\project\state.cpp(85) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>::vector<int>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<bool>,
1>              _Iter=int
1>          ]
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's creating a "2-dimensional" vector. It has `rows` number of rows, and each row has `cols` number of columns, and each cell is initialised to `false` (`0`).

The constructor of `vector` that it's using is the one that takes the number of elements it should have initially, along with what value to initialise each element with. So `visited` initially has `rows` elements, and each one is initialised with `std::vector<bool>(cols, 0)`, which initially has `cols` number of elements, and each one is initialised with `0` (which is `false`).

It's giving you that warning because it's converting `0`, an integer, to to `false`, a `bool`. You can fix it by replacing `0` with `false`.